# Passing multi line string in a Graphql mutation

Tags: graphql

Newbie to `GraphQL`.

I have to pass a multiline string (verbatim) inside a `mutation`. I have to read back the text in a seperate application and save it as a text file.

Here is what I am trying to do. I am trying this using `GraphiQL` client talking to a testing server in `GraphCool`.

```
mutation {
  createMessage(fullName: "John K", 
    message: "some very long text
message that appears on multiple lines 
with line breaks."    
}
```

And I get this error

```
{
"error": "Syntax error while parsing GraphQL query. Invalid input \"\"some very long text\\n\", expected StringValue, BooleanValue, NullValue, Variable, Comments, ObjectValue, EnumValue, NumberValue or ListValue (line 6, column 13):\n    message: \"some very long text\n            ^"
}
```

I can resolve the issue by replacing all line breaks with \n.

```
mutation {
  createMessage(fullName: "John K", 
    message: "some very long text\nmessage that appears on multiple\nlines\nwith line breaks."    
}
```

However, I am not sure though if it is the right approach because when I read back the message text and view it as a text file line breaks do not appear and all I get are \n.

Please help...

Comment: Btw - there seems to be a missing closing parenthesis in your query.

Answer (score 29):

Have tried with nodejs `"graphql": "0.13.2"`, it is possible to do it by wrapping your multiline string with `"""`:

(the line break should be still send to the graphql endpoint as `\n`, just graphiql probably help you escaped the \)

example:

this will fail `message: "some very long text
message that appears on multiple lines 
with line breaks."`

this should pass `message: """some very long text
message that appears on multiple lines 
with line breaks."""`

Comment: you saved my day, Thanks

Comment: http://spec.graphql.org/draft/#sec-String-Value.Block-Strings

Answer (score 8):

You could pass the string as a variable:

GraphQL query:

```
mutation($message: String) {
  createMessage(fullName: "John K", message: $message)
}
```

JS:

```
const message = `some very long text
message that appears on multiple lines 
with line breaks.`;
```

Not sure what GraphQL client you're using but from here you should be able to pass the variables to the client. With Apollo (react-apollo) it would look like this:

```
const CREATE_MESSAGE = gql`
  mutation($message: String) {
    createMessage(fullName: "John K", message: $message)
  }
`;

const message = `some very long text
message that appears on multiple lines 
with line breaks.`;

const CreateMessage = () => {    
  return (
    <Mutation mutation={CREATE_MESSAGE}>
      {(createMessage, { data }) => (
        <button onClick={() => createMessage({ variables: { message } })}>
          Create Message
        </button>
      )}
    </Mutation>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 5):

After spending lots of time it's work for me

if you are using GraphQL Apollo client
**`"""${yourText}"""`** will help you.

```
const yourText = "Lorem ipsum 
                  is simply dummy
                  standard dummy";
const input = {
                singleLine : "my name is kool",
                multiLine  : `""${yourText}""`
              }
```

Thank you K00L ;)

Answer (score 0):

Not possible in graphql, at the moment. There are [some RFC](https://github.com/facebook/graphql/pull/327), though.

So, I'm guessing, your best bet is to process your input and replace literal characters `\` and `n` with a newline character. Depending on content of your input, this might yield some false positives...

Comment: Thanks Sergio. So if there is no standard option than I guess there is no particular benefit of using '\n' - I mean I can pretty much use any character that I know will have to be replaced with newline after reading back. Is that correct?